# Choosing the right router for me

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My wifi router has finally died and I need a new one.

In the campus store there are three models:

- [tp-link TLWR941ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR941ND#app)
- [tp-link TLWR740N](http://www.tp-link.com/simulator/TL-WR740N_v1&v2/index.htm)
- [D-link N 300](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=814)

How can I tell if I can create with any of those two home network (one is encripted and one is open)? Also, is there a way, for any of those, to store a small website or protocol that will keep track of the open network access?

**Edit: I'll try to rewrite the question.**

I need a new router. I want my home network to:

1. Be encripted for the home users
2. Be open for guests and guys on the street who want to use my network for minor task.
3. Block users on the open network who are hogging on the network (I think 100 MB a day for a guest is far more than reasonable)
4. Will keep track of some user information on the open network (That way, if somebody is doing something ilegal on the web from my open network, I'll have a proof it wasn't me).

Is there any way to achieve that with one of the mentioned routers?

**Edit: I think I have found a solution**

[Is that so?](http://lifehacker.com/5791208/run-your-home-network-like-a-coffee-shop)

Comment: Pfft. Management tools in a consumer router...

Comment: I take it this isn't a trival task then.

Comment: It's not that it isn't a trivial task, but rather that consumer routers tend to not have these features since consumers usually don't need or want them. You'll need to look beyond your campus store, for something at least mid-end commercial-grade.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Which also suggest prices which are too high for me. Is there a chance I can forward any new user a local website that warns them or something?

Answer (score 1):

Well,You can host your own server by checking the Wireless router if it also supports a PORT FORWARDING/NAT/Firewall...and so on...also if you want to limit a bandwidth to your network...check or ask the seller if it also support (QOS)...

hosting your own small website, needs some port forwarding...a good service to your ISP...and a unique IP address(Static IP is better)...

try the D-Link because D-Link is the top and most widely used today.

Comment: The website should be on the local network. There is a good chance I wasn't clear on my question so I'll try and rewrite it.

Comment: You may want to read the question again...